# Using two "for" loops in a Mongo query - only passing first or last item

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have a query that aggregates based on a collection of documents (tickets). It looks for tickets with a pre-defined `DisplayLabel` and any `AssignedToPerson`. It then averages the `WorkingDuration` of each person's tickets and organizes them into a document of objects, with each object including the `AssignedToPerson` and the average of their `WorkingDuration`. It then sorts them by the newly created key called `WorkingDurationAvg`.

It grabs its `label` from a list of distinct `DisplayLabels` from the `Requests` collection.

```
var label = db.Requests.distinct("DisplayLabel");

var raw = db.Requests.aggregate([
  {$match:{"DisplayLabel": (label[5]) }},
  {
      $group: 
           {
            _id: "$AssignedToPerson",
            WorkingDurationAvg : { $avg :  "$WorkingDuration" }
           }

      },
  {$project:{_id : 1, "WorkingDurationAvg": 1}},
  {$sort : {"WorkingDurationAvg":1 }}
])
```

This gets assigned to `raw`, therefore `raw.result` would return something like this:

```
{
    "0" : {
        "_id" : "Bob",
        "WorkingDurationAvg" : 50.0000000000000000
    },
    "1" : {
        "_id" : "Jim",
        "WorkingDurationAvg" : 75.0000000000000000
    }
}
```

I then loop through each of the objects in `raw.result` and append a score to an array object that has the matching `label[5]`, into a predefined field called `time`, based on their position.

```
var count = raw.result.length;  

raw.result.forEach
(
  function()
  {for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
db.test.update(
  { "name" : (raw.result[i]._id), "dogs.capname" : (label[5]) },
  {$set: {"dogs.$.time": (count - i) / count }},
print(raw.result[i]._id)
)})
```

This works. The problem I'm running into, if you look at the first code snippet, is that I'm manually calling the `DisplayLabel` array number (in this example, I'm calling the `[5]`th element of `label`). I also call this `[5]`th element in the third code snippet. I want to iterate through each value of `label`. Meaning the query will run using `label[0]`, and then `label[1]`, and then `label[2]`, and so on...

Here's what I tried:

```
var label = db.Requests.distinct("DisplayLabel");

for (var x=0;x<100;x++){ //newly created for loop, goes up to 100

var raw = db.Requests.aggregate([
  {$match:{"DisplayLabel": (label[x]) }}, //[5] is changed to [x]
  {
      $group: 
           {
            _id: "$AssignedToPerson",
            WorkingDurationAvg : { $avg :  "$WorkingDuration" }
           }

      },
  {$project:{_id : 1, "WorkingDurationAvg": 1}},
  {$sort : {"WorkingDurationAvg":1 }}
])
// } <<-- A bracket here would return the same thing as entering "label[100]"
var count = raw.result.length;  

raw.result.forEach
(
  function()
  {for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
db.test.update(
  { "name" : (raw.result[i]._id), "dogs.capname" : (label[x]) },
  {$set: {"dogs.$.time": (count - i) / count }},
)})
} // <<-- A bracket here returns the same thing as entering "label[0]"
```

See the notes for what the curly brackets ending the "for" loop do.

From what I can tell, the problem is JavaScript based and not Mongo based. With the curly bracket higher up, the aggregation runs 101 times, but only returns the `[100]`th value into the next function. With the curly bracket at the end, the function only runs once and returns the result with the `[0]`th value. So the function either runs 101 times and THEN passes that value, or it's a "one and done".

I've also tried using [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323904/cannot-loop-mongodb-collection-functions) idea, but I can only get it to return the `[100]`th value using this method.

I know that I'm able to iterate through each `raw.result` because if I run this query as-is, but without everything below `raw.result.forEach`, I am able to print each iteration of `raw.result`. Adding the `forEach` limits me to the last iteratated item.

Comment: Did you try passing x to the anonymous function as per the linked answer you referenced?

Comment: @DaveCoast , here's what I tried: adding `(function (x) {` right below the initial `for` statement, changing all variables to `x`, and capping the parentheses and curly brackets off at the end. I then change the initial `for` statement to use `k`, and I call `(k)` before the very last curly bracket. This returns undefined values unless I revert the mentioned function back to being anonymous.